# Order by in Select statement in select list

Tags: oracle, select, sql-order-by

Can we use Order By clause when we are using Select Query in Select List ?

I want to write query like this :-

```
select col1
     , col2
     , (select colX from table2 where table2.col1=table1.col1 and rownum<2 order by colY desc) 
     , (select colXX from table3 where table3.col1=table1.col1 and rownum<2 order by colYY desc)
from table1;
```

I can't join the table. Its just example of what I want.

OK. Here is the thing.
I have following code written in SQL Server . I want to convert it into Oracle.

```
SELECT
BANK_ADDRESS1= (SELECT top 1 OWNER_ADDRESS1 
            FROM OWNER_ADDRESS OA, BANK_ACCOUNT
            WHERE PAYMENT.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID = BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID
                    and BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_ID = OA.OWNER_ID
                    order by Isnull (OA.primary_addr , 'N') desc),
PAYEE_ADD1 = (  SELECT top 1 OWNER_ADDRESS1 
                FROM OWNER_ADDRESS OA 
                WHERE OA.OWNER_ID = PAYEE_OWNER.OWNER_ID 
                order by Isnull (OA.primary_addr , 'N') desc ),
FROM    PAYMENT 
            inner JOIN PAYEE ON PAYMENT.PAYMENT_ID = PAYEE.PAYMENT_ID
            inner join OWNER PAYEE_OWNER on PAYEE_OWNER.OWNER_ID = PAYEE.PAYEE_NAME_ID
```

Hope this will clear what I really want.

Comment: The problem you'll run into is that the `ROWNUM < 2` will be applied before the `ORDER BY`; thus, you'll get whatever row is chosen first, then this single row will be sorted and returned :-). Any particular reason you can't join `table1`, `table2`, and `table3` together? From the statement you posted it appears the `col1` is common to all three...

Comment: @BobJarvis : Hey mate, I have edited the question. So it makes more sense now (I guess...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
select col1,
       col2,
       (select colX
          from (select col1, colX from table2 order by colY desc) table2
         where table2.col1 = table1.col1
           and rownum < 2),
       (select colXX
          from (select col1, colXX from table3 order by colYY desc) table3
         where table3.col1 = table1.col1
           and rownum < 2)
  from table1;
```

or this:

```
select col1,
       col2,
       (select max(colX) keep(dense_rank last order by colY)
          from table2
         where table2.col1 = table1.col1),
       (select max(colXX) keep(dense_rank last order by colYY)
          from table2
         where table2.col1 = table1.col1)
  from table1;
```

This subselect

```
(select colX from table2 where table2.col1=table1.col1 and rownum<2 order by colY desc)
```

even if it worked would not return what you expect because rownum is calculated before order by. You would get random row from those which fulfill the condition table2.col1 = table1.col1 .

Try

```
select (SELECT max(OWNER_ADDRESS1) keep(dense_rank last order by nvl(oa.primary_addr, 'N'))
          FROM OWNER_ADDRESS OA, BANK_ACCOUNT
         WHERE PAYMENT.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID = BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID
           and BANK_ACCOUNT.BANK_ID = OA.OWNER_ID) bank_address1,
       (SELECT max(OWNER_ADDRESS1) keep(dense_rank last order by nvl(oa.primary_addr, 'N'))
          FROM OWNER_ADDRESS OA
         WHERE OA.OWNER_ID = PAYEE_OWNER.OWNER_ID) payee_add1
  from PAYMENT
 inner JOIN PAYEE
    ON PAYMENT.PAYMENT_ID = PAYEE.PAYMENT_ID
 inner join OWNER PAYEE_OWNER
    on PAYEE_OWNER.OWNER_ID = PAYEE.PAYEE_NAME_ID
```

(I could have made some syntax errors, cannot check it).

Comment: Hey mate, I have edited the question. So it makes more sense now (I guess...).